# Filter rows where mirror-image delimiters are not paired

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr

I  have transcriptions of speech with "mirror-image" delimiters, i.e., paired symbols marking opening and, respectively, closing, such as `(` and `)` or `<` and `>`. The delimiter in this data is the square bracket:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:9,
  Utterance = c("[but if I came !ho!me",                         # <- closing square bracket is missing
                "=[ye::a:h]",                                    # OK!
                "=[yeah] I mean [does it",                       # <- closing square bracket is missing
                "bu[t if (.) you know",                          # <- closing square bracket is missing
                "=ye::a:h]",                                     # <- opening square bracket is missing
                "[that's right] YEAH (laughs)] [ye::a:h]",        # <- opening square bracket is missing
                "cos I've [heard] very sketchy stories",         # OK!
                "[cos] I've [heard very sketchy [stories]",      # <- closing square bracket is missing 
                "oh well] that's great"                          # <- opening square bracket is missing       
))
```

I want to filter those rows where either at least one of the opening or at least one the closing delimiters is missing (as this represents a transcription error).
I'm actually doing fine with this `str_count` method:

```
library(string)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(str_count(Utterance, "\\[|\\]") %in% c(1,3,5,7,9))
  id                                Utterance
1  1                    [but if I came !ho!me
2  3                  =[yeah] I mean [does it
3  4                     bu[t if (.) you know
4  5                                =ye::a:h]
5  6  [that's right] YEAH (laughs)] [ye::a:h]
6  8 [cos] I've [heard very sketchy [stories]
7  9                    oh well] that's great
```

but was wondering whether regexes could be devised to detect the strings with missing elements directly. I've been trying this regex, for missing closing brackets:

```
p_op <- "(?<!.{0,10}\\[.{0,10})\\].*$"       
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Utterance, p_op))
```

which works well, and this for missing closing brackets, which does not capture all matches:

```
p_cl<- "\\[(?!.*\\]).*$"    
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Utterance, p_cl))
```

How can the pattern or the patterns be formulated better?

Comment: `str_count` is not enough since it will fail in a scenario like `oh well] that's [great`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, using `purrr::map_dfr`.

**EXPLANATION**

I provide, in what follows, an explanation for my solution, as asked for by @ChrisRuehlemann:

1. With `str_extract_all(df$Utterance, "\\[|\\]")`, we extract all `[` and `]` of each utterance as a list and according to the order they appear in the utterance.
2. We iterate all lists created previously for the utterances. However, we have a list of square brackets. So, we need to beforehand collapse the list into a single string of square brackets (`str_c(.x, collapse = "")`).
3. We compare the string of square brackets of each utterance with a string like the following `[][][]...` (`str_c(rep("[]", length(.x)/2), collapse = "")`). If these two strings are not equal, then  square brackets are missing!
4. When `map_dfr` finishes, we end up with a column of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which we can use to filter the original dataframe as wanted.

```r
library(tidyverse)    

str_extract_all(df$Utterance, "\\[|\\]") %>% 
  map_dfr(~ list(OK = str_c(.x, collapse = "") != 
            str_c(rep("[]", length(.x)/2), collapse = ""))) %>% 
  filter(df,.)

#>   id                                Utterance
#> 1  1                    [but if I came !ho!me
#> 2  3                  =[yeah] I mean [does it
#> 3  4                     bu[t if (.) you know
#> 4  5                                =ye::a:h]
#> 5  6  [that's right] YEAH (laughs)] [ye::a:h]
#> 6  8 [cos] I've [heard very sketchy [stories]
#> 7  9                    oh well] that's great
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add comments on the individual steps? Looks like a cool solution!

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisRuehlemann ! Explanation inserted. If you have some further question, please ask me -- I will be happy to answer you.

Comment: That's a really clever solution. Thanks a lot, I learnt a lot from it! Have even translated its logic into dplyr, which I'm more familiar with: `df %>%
  mutate(
    delims = lapply(str_extract_all(Utterance, "\\[|\\]"), paste0, collapse = ""),
    valid = str_count(delims, "\\[\\]") == nchar(delims)/2) %>%
  filter(valid == FALSE)`

Answer (score 2):

May use the pattern (`\\[[^\\]]+(\\[|$)|(^|\\])[^\\[]+\\]`) in `str_detect`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
   filter(str_detect(Utterance, "\\[[^\\]]+(\\[|$)|(^|\\])[^\\[]+\\]"))
  id                                Utterance
1  1                    [but if I came !ho!me
2  3                  =[yeah] I mean [does it
3  4                     bu[t if (.) you know
4  5                                =ye::a:h]
5  6  [that's right] YEAH (laughs)] [ye::a:h]
6  8 [cos] I've [heard very sketchy [stories]
7  9                    oh well] that's great
```

Here we check for a opening bracket `[` followed by one or more characters that are not `]` followed by a `[` or the end of the string (`$`) or a similar pattern for the closing bracket

Comment: Second solution is great. First solution doesn't work for strings like `"oh well] that's [great"`!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a function to validate (nested) parenthesis, here is a stack based one.

```
valid_delim <- function(x, delim = c(open = "[", close = "]"), max_stack_size = 10L){
  f <- function(x, delim, max_stack_size){
    if(is.null(names(delim))) {
      names(delim) <- c("open", "close")
    }
    if(nchar(x) > 0L){
      valid <- TRUE
      stack <- character(max_stack_size)
      i_stack <- 0L
      y <- unlist(strsplit(x, ""))
      for(i in seq_along(y)){
        if(y[i] == delim["open"]){
          i_stack <- i_stack + 1L
          stack[i_stack] <- delim["close"]
        } else if(y[i] == delim["close"]) {
          valid <- (stack[i_stack] == delim["close"]) && (i_stack > 0L)
          if(valid)
            i_stack <- i_stack - 1L
          else break
        }
      }
      valid && (i_stack == 0L)
    } else NULL
  }
  x <- as.character(x)
  y <- sapply(x, f, delim = delim, max_stack_size = max_stack_size)
  unname(y)
}

library(dplyr)

valid_delim(df$Utterance)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

df %>% filter(valid_delim(Utterance))
#  id                             Utterance
#1  2                            =[ye::a:h]
#2  7 cos I've [heard] very sketchy stories
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not the expected output and not regex.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Ok, sorry for the noise. But is the expected output the negation of the function's return value?

Comment: Yes, that's right